# how to submit ajax data to .js.erb rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to get the data sent from ajax request in my `method_name.js.erb`.

It sends the request successfully but the problem is that I can't able to get

the data being sent in ajax.

**actual ajax code:**

```
var a = 1;
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: "/admin/method_name/",
   dataType : 'script',
   data: {var: a}
});
```

**method_name.js.erb code:**

```
var_is = var #I want var value here
$('#dialog').modal("show");
```

**Ajax Link:**

```
Started GET "/admin/method_name?var=1&_=1495145400545" for 127.0.0.1 at
2017-05-19 03:12:23 +0500
```

Any way I can get ajax data in `.js.erb`?

Answer (score 2):

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: "/admin/method_name/",
   dataType : 'script',
   data: {var: a}
});
```

Will create a request to `/admin/method_name/?var="foo"`.

You can get the value of the `var` param in your Rails app by `params[:var]` - just like with any other param.

Comment: Is there any way that I can receive this all data to my `method_name.js.erb`? From controller or any other way please explain? I know what you mean by saying this but I was going with some unique way to handle it. I could be wrong with respect to my logic.

Comment: Maybe you should start by learning the basics of rails before you try tackling ajax? The params hash is how you access the incoming parameters. There is no real way I can explain this to you if you don't even grasp the basic concepts.http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: Well being polite, you are not getting me with what I am trying to say again and even in  question as well. Simple answer could be not a possibility or any other good answer. Thanks.

Comment: You are making less and less sense. Sorry.

Comment: A very simple solution was: In `method_name.js.erb` I did `<% puts params[:var] %>`. Its that simple. My only point was to get it in `method_name.js.erb` without going to controller etc. It 4AM here and i was so exhaust with it. I am sorry if I said anything in wrong way. :) 
I am still learning rails but I respect my seniors a lot. Sorry but downvoting does not solves the real problem well. :)

Answer (score 0):

Given this code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: "/admin/method_name/",
  dataType : 'script',
  data: {var: a}
});
```

You can access the param titled `var` in your controller action like this:

```
def method_name
  @var = params[:var]
end
```

Now, when rails renders your `method_name.js.erb` file, you will have access to the `@var` parameter from the controller.

The way rails passes variables from controllers to views using the `@variable_name` syntax is the exact same as the way rails passes variables to `js.erb` files.

To confirm that everything is working properly, write the following in your `method_name.js.erb` file:

```
console.log("<%= j @var %>");
```

If you open your browser logs you should see the value of the `a` parameter you passed into the controller via your ajax request.

For more information on rails and ajax, you can [read the documentation here.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#an-introduction-to-ajax)